# Movies won't stream to TV with minidlna (debian) but music/photos will

Tags: debian, dlna, video-codecs

I am trying to setup a media server running Debian 7.8 and the latest release of minidlna.  My TV is a Toshiba 50L7300UC and can play music and show images via the DLNA.  It will play .mkv videos too, but when I try to play an .mp4 video it says "Unsupported file".  If I put the same .mp4 video on a USB, the TV plays it no problem.

How can I get minidlna to play .mp4 videos?  Thank you.

Comment: I just learned that I can stream an .mp4 video to my phone via minidlna, but the same .mp4 won't stream to the TV (and it would play on the TV via USB).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's my understanding that the video is a .mp4 but it uses MPEG-4 compression (.mp4 is just a container holding: the video, audio, subtitles, chapters).  So the TV needs to support MPEG-4.  Found the answer from deep in the manual (http://support.toshiba.ca/support/ceg/manuals/LEDTV/L4300UC_L7300UC_E.pdf), MPEG-4 is supported via USB but not via a media server:

**File specifications:**

*USB use:*

File format: MPEG2 PS, MPEG2 TS, MPEG-2 VOB, AVI, MOV,MP4, ASF, DivX, Xvid, MKV, Flash Video (FLV1), 3GPP, MotionJPEGVideo: MPEG2, H.264, **MPEG-4** part2, DivX, Xvid, VC-1 (WMV9), RealVideo 8,9,10, Sorenson H.263 (FLV1), JPEG

*Content on a connected Media Server:*

File format: MPEG2 PS, MPEG2 TS, MP4 (Low resolution)